# Python converting strings and ints to an unknown, but given data type

Tags: python, numpy, type-conversion

I have an assignment, I'm given a list of tuples, that contain string of numbers, ints or float for example, I get a tuple that contains `(ID,Class,Grade,Height)`:

```
A = [('123121','24',23,12.0),(23667,64,78,15.5)]
```

I am also given a list of tuples, so that each tuple contains the thing I want to convert, and what to convert it to.
for example I get this list:

`types=[('ID','int'),(grade,'S15'),('height','float'),('class','int')]`

now, I do not know what each value in the type tuple will be, it could be int, float, dtype, whatever.
I searched and I found this piece of code:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Type

T = TypeVar('T')

def cast(input, cast_type: Type[T]):
    casted_value = cast_type(input)
    return casted_value
```

it seems to work fine for int, float, string, but for `S15` which is a numpty dtype, it doesn't work and I get the error:

```
casted_value = cast_type(input)
TypeError: Preliminary-API: Flexible/Parametric legacy DType '<class 'numpy.dtype[bytes_]'>' can only be instantiated using `np.dtype(...)`
```

in my example the wanted output after printing A after conversions should be:

```
A = [(123121,b'24',23.0,12),(23667,b'64',78.0,15)]
```

how can I convert something to a given but unknown until given data type?

Comment: You say 'S15 [..] is a dtype', can you provide a reference to why you say that? It's not a datatype in basic Python, and your tags don't provide a hint - are you talking about a numpy data type? And if so, which one exactly? (you seem to be talking about these numbers, which would require using a version numpy in your code https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_data_types.htm)

Comment: I edited my question, yes I am talking about numpy data type. I don't have a reference to S15 because it is a numpy dtype which given to me as an example of a type I need to convert to. I tried to searched for it online, all I got is that is a numpy dtype

Comment: `types` looks like specification for a compound dtype, to make a `structured array`.  You can read all about that.  I don't know if `typing` can handle structured arrays and their dtype.

Comment: I'm asking if there is a way to do generic conversion, if I want to convert it to numpy dtype, or int, or float, or whatever, I can just pass the argument to the function that converts, and return the converted type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want, but here's how to make a `structured array` with this list of tuples and dtype specification.

```
In [90]: A = [('123121','24',23,12.0),(23667,64,78,15.5)]


In [92]: types=[('ID','int'),('grade','S15'),('height','float'),('class','int')]
```

With matching list of tuples, the basic `array` function produces:

```
In [93]: arr = np.array(A, dtype=types)
```

It's full `repr` display is:

```
In [94]: arr
Out[94]: 
array([(123121, b'24', 23., 12), ( 23667, b'64', 78., 15)],
      dtype=[('ID', '<i4'), ('grade', 'S15'), ('height', '<f8'), ('class', '<i4')])
```

and the more compact `str`:

```
In [95]: print(arr)
[(123121, b'24', 23., 12) ( 23667, b'64', 78., 15)]
```

This is (2,) shape array, with 4 fields.  `arr[0]` gets one record.  `arr['height']` gets one field.